# Form validation stop at first iteration

Tags: javascript, validation

I'm trying to write js code for form validation. I came up with this code where I first want to check if fields are empty:

```
var validationInfo = {"displayname" : {}, "password" : {}, "email" : {}, "username" : {}};

document.newUser.onsubmit = function () {
    for(key in validationInfo) {
        var field = document.getElementById(key);
        if(field.value == "") {
            field.setAttribute("style","background-color: yellow;");
            field.select();
            return false;
        }//checking empty fields
    }//check validation
    return true;
}
```

When I submit only first field of form turns yellow, so I think that validation stops after first iteration. Is "return false" positioned wrong?

Second question, if I would want to check something else like if fields is empty, should I do it in the same or another function? What is the best practise?

Thanks

Comment: Remove `return false;`

Comment: Return causes it to stop iterating, imo

Comment: @kristjanreinhold: That's a fact, not an opinion ;-)

Comment: @KrishR if I remove that, whats stooping it to submit with empty fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a variable `_valid` and assign it to false if any validation error occurs. Return this variable.

```
var validationInfo = {"displayname" : {}, "password" : {}, "email" : {}, "username" : {}};

document.newUser.onsubmit = function () {
    var _valid = true;
    for(key in validationInfo) {
        var field = document.getElementById(key);
        if(field.value == "") {
            field.setAttribute("style","background-color: yellow;");
            field.select();
            _valid = false;
        }//checking empty fields
    }//check validation
    return _valid;
}
```

Comment: Why `_valid`, and not something that doesn't use a random underscore, and is a little more descriptive, like: `formIsValid`? Just nitpicking here ;-)